# Stdout string manipulate, delete all after a word per line

Tags: command-line, sed

My string look like this..

```
foo<.............................. 
bar</............................
```

I want to pipe for output as

```
foo
bar
```

Delete all characters after a first `<` found each line.

Comment: Tried splitting the string by line, then by `<` and just outputting the first element per line?

Comment: @Lekensteyn I would appreciate if you help me to solve it with `sed`, I really want to know that one.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is basic sed. Using sed is not difficult once you know [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info/). A basic `sed` command for reading the input and stripping every `<` and the following part if it exist, then printing the line (may be modified):

```
$ echo 'foo<....' | sed 's/<.*//'
foo
```

`sed` uses [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info/), the relevant manual page text for [`sed(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=sed) that applies to the above command:

> s/regexp/replacement/
>   Attempt  to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.  The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp

Alternative using `cut` ([manual page for `cut(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=cut)), "split the string by `<` and take the `1`st field.

```
echo 'foo<....' | cut -d'<' -f1
```

Alternative using `grep`, "match only everything containing characters of the set a to z (case insensitive)" ([manual page of `grep(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=grep)):

```
echo 'foo<....' | grep -io '[a-z]*'
```

(note: I took the liberty to use `[a-z]*`, meaning "zero or more occurrences of a letter", because grep won't return an empty line when using the `-o` option)

Alternative using awk, using the same idea of `cut` ([manual page of `awk(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=awk)):

```
echo 'foo<....' | awk -F '<' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample:

`cat textWithFooBar.txt | cut -d '<' -f 1 > output.txt`

Comment: Perfect use for `cut` except for the "Useless use of cat" -- `cut -d '<' -f 1 < textWithFooBar.txt > output.txt`